# Communication desktop between multiple android devices on lan

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, lan

I'm coding a java app which consists 2 parts (android and desktop). There will be one desktop and multiple android devices.

I want to;

1. send data from desktop to android device which I choose,
2. send data from one of android devices to desktop app only.

I want to send data by using local area network. All devices will be connected same network.

It must work on different places. If I use socket programming (I guess I have to);

1. is it possible to find lan ip addresses all of android devices which is connected on network?
2. how can these android devices know the desktop's ip address? Because you know it changes network to network.

Comment: Just to give you some useful terms to search for: [https://www.google.de/search?q=client+server+autodiscovery+udp+java](https://www.google.de/search?q=client+server+autodiscovery+udp+java)

Comment: Keep in mind that some wireless networks isolate clients from each other. This commonly happens in hotels, airports, coffee shops but is also offered/enabled in some home wifi routers.

Comment: So you don't suggest to use lan for communication in hotels coffee shops etc. But if I use wan, scalability will be a really big problem.  @philipp-reichart

Comment: @RasimAndıran Scalability depends on how much data you need to send how fast and to how many devices. If you describe the context of your question (purpose, data size, desired speed, number of devices), we can likely help you more.

Comment: Okey. System consists clusters. Every cluster contains one desktop and numerous android devices. We don't know how many clusters. Clusters are numerous,too. Clusters are unconnected. Data size is not big. I don't guess exactly but really small data. I want to create 2 programs; one of is for desktop, the other one is android devices. And I mention that programs features up above.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

1. On all devices, send pings to broadcast address.
2. Try to connect (TCP) to all clients that answered (not sure if every device will answer to broadcast ping). If connection is established, the other client is one of yours, running your application
3. Find out whether it's Desktop or Android by the messages itself.